# What is best practice when writing code for dom manipulation?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-manipulation

So I'm creating a web app that takes recipe information and prints it to the DOM based on a food recipe API.  I'm taking the JSON information and manipulating the dom HEAVILY.  It's dawning on me that this code is pretty unreadable.  Here is a segment:

```
//create ingredient title

const ingredientTitle = document.createElement("p");

const ingredientTitleTextNode = document.createTextNode("Ingredients");

ingredientTitle.appendChild(ingredientTitleTextNode);

const ingredientTitleParent = document.querySelector(".recipe-ingredients-item");

ingredientTitleParent.appendChild(ingredientTitle);

//create ingredient title end



//create ingredient UL and LIs

const ingredients = selectedItemJson.hits[0].recipe.ingredientLines;


const ingredientUl = document.createElement("ul");

for (let j = 0; j < ingredients.length; j++) {

  const ingredientLi = document.createElement("li");

  const ingredientTextNode = document.createTextNode(ingredients[j]);

  ingredientLi.appendChild(ingredientTextNode);

  ingredientUl.appendChild(ingredientLi);

}

const ingredientParent = document.querySelector(".recipe-ingredients-item");

ingredientParent.appendChild(ingredientUl);

//create ingredient UL and LIs end
```

There is going to be a LOT more of this. So is this bad practice? and if so what can I do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe look into using Angular JS or jQuery

Comment: The obvious answer is to use the API of a well designed library like jQuery

Comment: I need to learn jQuery but I really don't like the syntax for some reason :( why would jQuery help me do this?

Comment: I'll look into angular now nick

Comment: If you want something simpler, use jQuery, the syntax is a little strange at first but it can be very powerful. angular can be a little harder to learn

Comment: You can use the property `innerHTML` of DOM node to set its HTML. for example, `document.body.innerHTML += '<span>Added by JS code</span>';` will append a `<span>` element to the end of the document. For more details, see [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Comment: The obvious answer to a question about good practices while writing code for DOM manipulation is obviously *not* "use a framework".

Comment: This is not a question suitable for stack overflow. There is no clear answer for this.

Comment: With a empty line between all your lines of code, yes, it is hard to read. Why?

Comment: If you want more readable code, maybe separate your code in different functions with clear name and comments what they do.

Comment: @JosuGoñi I've just seen it layed out like that in books.

Comment: @MarkBaijens noted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) quick and simple example using innerHTML:

```
var html = "";
var list = [
    {
        name: "name",
        components: [
            {name: "ingredient1", quantity: "q1"},
            {name: "ingredient2", quantity: "q2"}
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "name2",
        components: [
            {name: "ingredient3", quantity: "q1"},
            {name: "ingredient4", quantity: "q2"}
        ]
    },

]

for (var x = 0; x < list.length; x++){
    var item = list[x];
    html += "<h1>" + item.name + "</h1>";
    html +="<ul>";
    for (var y = 0; y < item.components.length; y++){
        var component = item.components[y];
        html += "<li>" + component.name + ", quantity: " + component.quantity + "</li>";
    }
    html += "</ul>";
}
var dom = document.createElement("p");
dom.innerHTML = html;
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(dom);
```

2) using direct dom

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var p = document.createElement("p");
body.appendChild(p);

for (var x = 0; x < list.length; x++){
    var item = list[x];
    var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    h1.innerText = item.name;
    p.appendChild(h1);
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    for (var y = 0; y < item.components.length; y++){
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var component = item.components[y];
        li.innerText = component.name + ", quantity: " + component.quantity;
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    p.appendChild(ul);
}
```

JSPerf test InnerHTML vs direct dom

[image]

https://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-dom-append/1

Comment: Using innerHTML while concatenating strings is horribly slow. Do not use this.

Comment: well what do you mean by horribly slow - for quick solution it would not be much slower than manually creating dom elements. if user has no experience with advanced templating, this will help to solve his problem quickly.

Comment: I mean *horribly* slow. I say it out of experience with a simple TODO list app. Really slow. Seriously. Once I changed it to using the DOM the improvement was dramatic.

Comment: Thanks, I might just have to do this for readability sake.  Although, I chose not to go that route initially because it is apparently deemed bad practice and appendChild() is meant to be better ?

Comment: This is a perfectly acceptable method.  Repeated small DOM insertions can be slow, because the browser has to reflow the document every time you insert a new DOM node -- don't innerHTML every ingredient separately in a loop -- but a single insertion of a large chunk of html is fine.

Comment: @DanielBeck The huge performance problem I think it is on the string concatenation. Try a bigger array if you are curious. My performance problems started to grow as I added TODO items to my app.

Comment: No, string concatenation is not slow either.  I can't really speak to your experience with your app, but my guess is that you were doing incremental DOM manipulation, which *is* significantly slower than single large insertions.

Comment: @DanielBeck I wasn't. I had a method that built the list, and once it was ready, it replaced de old list. Changing from string concatenation to `createElement` was a big change. From seconds to milliseconds.

Comment: Well, though that doesn't match my experience or any benchmark I've ever seen, I'm glad that worked out for you.